# Unable to zipfiles within folders using Python

Tags: python, zip

I have multiple folders within a directory (D:/zptest). Each folder has many files. I am trying to zip all these files with in that folder and save the file in the same folder with the "foldername.zip" I have written a script for this but unfortunately it's throwing the following error

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
```

Can some body help me?

I am using the following code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os, zipfile
from pathlib import Path
loc=r'D:\zipfilelist'
p=Path(r'D:\zptest')
for x in p.iterdir():
   x1=str(x)
   print("Processing: " + x1)
   dirs=os.listdir(x1)
   for file in dirs:
      file=os.path.join(x1,file)
      zip = zipfile.ZipFile(, "a", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
      zip.write(file)
      zip.close()
```

Comment: You do not have access to the particular folder that you are trying to zip, or file location that you are trying to write to.

Either run the script as superuser if you really want to supersede permissions, or check user permissions.

Comment: The `zipfile.ZipFile(, "a", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)` looks like it's missing a its first argument.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help. I was able to complete a working code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os, zipfile, datetime, time
from pathlib import Path

p=Path(r'V:\NAR_ARCHIVE')
for x in p.iterdir():
x1=str(x)
print("Processing: " + x1)
#zipfilename = "%s.zip" % (x.stem)
loc=r'Y:\StorageReports\NAR_Zips'
loc=loc + '\\' + x.stem + '.zip'
print (loc)
print(x.stem)
dirs=os.listdir(x1)

#print(dirs)
for file in dirs:
sdate=datetime.datetime(2015,5,30)
edate=datetime.datetime(2015,6,7)
file=os.path.join(x1,file)
crtime=time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(file))
d1=datetime.datetime.strptime(crtime,"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
if d1<edate and d1>sdate:
file=os.path.join(x1,file)
print(file)
#logFile = open(r"Y:\StorageReports\NAR_Zips\logfile.log","a")    
#print >> logFile,message
zip = zipfile.ZipFile(loc, "a", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
zip.write(file)
zip.close()
```

Comment: I would like to optimize this further. Currently dates are entered manually. But I want dates to be picked manually (Sunday to Saturday). This code will run on a sunday and it should pick last weeks date. Can someone help me? The code above has sample dates.